# Ansible deploys Docker container to wrong Vagrant VM

Tags: jenkins, docker, vagrant, ansible, containers

*Updated after trying out @konstantin-suvorov solution.  Now it doesn't do anything.*

I have created 5 Vagrant VMs, all from bento/xenial64 and have then used Ansible to deploy docker onto all of the machines.

When I then attempt to use Ansible to deploy a container onto a remote VM, it says that it has done it, but the container is running on the local machine.

My 4 machines are:
control
cluster01
cluster02
cluster03
cluster04

Docker is up and running on all 5

From VM control, I run

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts/local jenkins.yml
```

My inventory file is

```
[control]
10.100.100.100

[cluster]
10.100.100.101
10.100.100.102
10.100.100.103
10.100.100.104

[master]
10.100.100.101
```

This is my Jenkins playbook

```
---
- hosts: master
  remote_user: ubuntu
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - jenkins
```

and this is my jenkins role

```
---
- name: Container is running
  docker_container:
    name: jenkins
    image: "jenkins:{{ jenkins_version }}"
    ports: 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - "{{ jenkins_home_dir }}:/var/jenkins_home"
```

After running the ansible-playbook, with very very very verbose option, and adding inventory for the vagrant machines,

```
vagrant@control:/vagrant$ ansible-playbook -i hosts/local jenkins.yml -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory -vvvv
Using /vagrant/ansible.cfg as config file
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc

PLAYBOOK: jenkins.yml **********************************************************
1 plays in jenkins.yml

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ansible_connection=local` from *remote* nodes.

If `ansible_connection` is `local`, Ansible runs all tasks on local (control) host.

Comment: I removed the ansible_connection=local.  It now doesn't do anything.  No errors either

Comment: why to `-i` parameters?

Comment: One is for the logical structure of the nodes in the inventory.  The other is auto generated by vagrant with the connection credentials

Comment: Things doesn't work this way. There may be only one inventory. Use directory-inventory, if you need to split records between multiple files.

Comment: A mixture of problems.  Once I fixed the inventory using host_vars and removed the ansible_connection settings, everything kind of worked.  Other issues are not related.